# Is two phase commit an implementation of linearizability?

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed, consistency

Most implementations of two-phase commit, as I understand them, require all nodes of a system to agree on the value before committing locally and only after they have all committed locally respond to the client- is this a correct understanding of 2PC?

Does this then make 2PC an implementation of the linearizable sequential consistency model?

I was thinking that because the value returned to the client will never be out of date and it's happening in real time that means it's truly linearizable right?

I never hear 2PC described as linearizable though so think there is something here I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be, and there are many better algorithms that survive crash failures (which 2PC doesn't). That said, you can use two phase commit to help implement linearizability or strong serializability.

The "value returned to the client will never be out of date and it's happening in real time" statement completely ignores the presence of caches and queues, which easily allow you to read from the past or write to the future, so watch out for that.

Comment: So my explanation of 2PC was simplistic and real-world implementations may include nuances which could make them not linearizable right? Does my hypothetical 2PC not often exist in real world systems?

Comment: 2PC is both less tolerant (doesn't handle any kind of failure) and slower (needs reply from all parties, rather than e.g. a majority) than raft/paxos/... but it is simpler. I don't know of any real-world production-ready system that uses 2pc. Just the fact that a single dropped packet can deadlock the entire system, requiring an unsafe manual reboot, should be enough to never be used in real world systems.

Comment: well oracle claims to have a 2PC implementation, is this not true 2PC then? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_txns003.htm#ADMIN12222

Comment: I bet it doesn't handle dropped packets or server crashes. Can't find anything about failures in the docs. For marketing/business reasons, it's often better to implement well-known but useless features, in case someone has it on their requirements checklist when selecting a product.